# What are common homonyms and synonyms between different webplatforms/webproducts?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net, python, html

I am ASP.NET developer.

Yesterday I started to write website content on and support customers of plugin(s) (for example,  captchas, etc.) supporting different web CMSes (Content Management Systems) on different platforms mainly PHP-based ones (like [WordPress](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordPress), [Joomla](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla), [Drupal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drupal),  etc.) though they can be for any (non-PHP) CMS (like [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke)).

I am trying to reuse my knowledge of ASP.NET web (user and/or server) controls, CMS [DotNetNuke](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DotNetNuke) (dotnetnuke.com) modules, styles, CSS, master page, template, etc.

What are the differences between definitions of PHP web CMS (though it could have been written in a different language, like Python, etc.) plugin vs. MS Add-in, ASP.NET webcontrol?

What are possible [homonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homonym) and synonyms a web developer/supporter between different web platforms, CMS-es, frameworks a (web)developer/supporter should be aware of?

Update:
@Rafe Kettler, honestly, after 2 days of writing web content for a (PHP, Python) plugin (captcha), I could not get what are its differences against asp.net webcontrol. 
Why are they called differently?

There are more terms I have difficulties with between CMS-es.

Note that I should communicate with both internal and external (of customers) developers developing or deploying the same plugin (product) in different platforms, languages, CMS.

Update2:
I do not pretend having the same instructions for different CMS-es.
Instructions are specific per each CMS, but marketing (website content) should be in the same. better most common and less confusing, terms.

Honestly, I am not going to study PHP and CMS-es in all possible languages (frameworks), specific responses and content will be written by developers. I am after marketing terms of a "plugin" common and unambiguous between CMS-es.

Comment: Honestly, is you did ASP.NET you should be good. It's not terribly different (especially if you're working with a CMS, which makes eveything that much easier and uniform)

Comment: Python is properly written like that, not as "PYTHON"; it isn't an acronym.

Comment: @KARL WE KNOW I JUST SOMETIMES CAN"T TURN OFF CAPS LOCK

Comment: PYTHON is capitalized in order to distract spell-checker, beautificators, keyboard language convertors and avoid confusion with SNAKES!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to support different CMSes, your existing knowledge of ASP.NET should cover you on most of the stuff you need to know. As for terminology, it varies from CMS to CMS. It would be helpful to read some tutorials on the various CMSes that you'll be supporting (the most popular ones are definitely Wordpress, Drupal, and Joomla, but like you said, there are others).

Especially important things that most CMSes have are plugins and themes, but I'm sure you already know what those are. Themes are pre-packaged visual layouts, and plugins are pieces of software designed to add functionality (like Google Analytics, allowing users to share articles on Facebook, etc.). PHP isn't so buzzword-filled as the .NET stuff is.

If you'll actually be editing code on the CMSes, it would be very helpful to learn PHP and its associated terms.

Comment: The problem is that plug-in-s are supported and should be described for developers of various CMS on various platforms  like, for example, (ASP.NET) DNN and (PHP) Drupal. I should communicate with developers of customers and with internal developers coding plug-ins.

Comment: @vgv8 that varies vastly from CMS to CMS. Different ones will have different APIs.

Comment: So, the situation is that much desperate? I cannot write technical instructions on web site without potentially invoking ambiguities/difficulties  between different platform developers?

Comment: @vgv8 pretty much. I don't know how anyone expects you to support all CMSes and write general docs for writing plugins for all of them.

Comment: Yeah, can't be done. You'll have to write one instruction per CMS.

Comment: Lennart, I'd like to see it in answer because it is an unobvious conclusion that should have more visibility for help or different opinions

Answer (score 1):

Plone calls plugins "Products", and calls MVC controllers "views". That's common confusions.